# Conversion of recursive C function into ARM assembly?

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, arm

For a homework assignment, I've been given a recursive C function to count integer partitions that I need to convert to ARM assembly. Things I know about ARM assembly:

1) `R0` will hold the return value of a call

2) `R1`, `R2`, and `R3` are argument registers

The code is as follows:

```
int count_partitions(int n, int m) { 

if (n == 0) 
    return 1; 

else if(n < 0) 
    return 0; 

else if (m == 0) 
    return 0; 

else 
    return count_partitions(n - m, m) + count_partitions(n, m - 1); 
}
```

I believe I have done the first 3 `if & else-if` statements correctly. My logic for the final `else` statement was to find count_partitions(n, m-1), store that onto the stack, then find `count_partitions(n-m, m)`, and add that to the previous return value I got from the stack - however my code does not seem to work?

I've attached my attempted solution and have color coded the different segments of C code and their corresponding assembly code. Could anyone let me know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using gcc's (or clangs) ability to generate assembler code for guidance?

Comment: I can't quite decipher the tiny unreadable picture of code, but [here's what a compiler thinks](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-O2+-marm',source:'int+count_partitions(int+n,+int+m)+%7B+%0Aif+(n+%3D%3D+0)+%0A++++return+1%3B+%0Aelse+if(n+%3C+0)+%0A++++return+0%3B+%0Aelse+if+(m+%3D%3D+0)+%0A++++return+0%3B+%0Areturn+count_partitions(n+-+m,+m)+%2B+count_partitions(n,+m+-+1)%3B+%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3), anyway.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that you will ever need to combine assembler and recursion in any real-world application. Real-world uses for recursion are very few, in almost every case there exists a better, non-recursive alternative. In particular, using recursion in embedded systems is pure nonsense in 99.99% of the cases. It's a good way to get a lawsuit though.

Comment: I understand, but this is a homework assignment so I have to try and figure it out regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see several problems:

- You assume that `n` is in `r1`. This is actually in `r0`. `m` will be in `r1`, not r2.
- For this reason, you need to save both `r0` and `r1`.

One cleaner solution would be to use something like this:

```
_count_partitions:
    ...             ; First part with comparison
                    ; but r1->r0 and r2->r1

    push {r4-r5}
    mov r4, r0      ; saved value of n
    mov r5, r1      ; saved value of m
    sub r0, r4, r5  ; n = n-m
    bl _count_partitions

    sub r1, r5, #1  ; m = m-1
    mov r5, r1      ; result of first function
    mov r0, r4      ; restore n
    bl _count_partitions

    add r0, r0, r5  ; cumulative result
    pop {r4,r5}
    pop {pc}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this after the CMP command and jump your function:

BEQ label ; BRANCH EQUAL

BNE label ; BRANCH NOT EQUAL

BLE label ; BRANCH LESS THAN EQUAL

BLT label ; BRANCH LESS THAN

BGE label ; BRANCH GREATER THAN EQUAL

BGT label ; BRANCH GREATER THAN